# Whats wrong in updating Jtable to the database.?

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

I am trying to update the following content to the database, ie, a table and a date text field, but when trying to update the jtable to the database its not working properly and i am getting a number exception. What code should i add/change? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;

public class Table1 {

JFrame frame;
JComboBox credit;
String[] rowNames = {
    "Vasan Phalke", "Pansare", "Anil Kg", "Suresh", "Total Credit", ""};
String[] colNames = {"Name", "Qty", "Rate/ Kg", "Total Amt."};
JTable table;
DefaultTableModel model;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
JButton saveButton;
JTextField dateField;
JLabel dateLabel;

public Table1() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    credit = new JComboBox<>(rowNames);
    dateLabel = new JLabel("Date");
    dateField = new JTextField(20);
    saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
   {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
         {
try
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:TomsJava");

    String i5Date1 = dateField.getText();

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE DailyAnalysis SET Total_Credit = ? where Date = i5Date1");
    ps.setDouble(1, (Double) table.getValueAt(5,3));

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DailyAnalysis");

    rs.moveToInsertRow();
    rs.updateString("Date1",i5Date1);
    rs.close();
    ps.close();
    conn.close();
                }

catch(SQLException e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException z)
{
    System.out.println(z);
}
catch(NumberFormatException n)
{
    System.out.println(n);
}
         }
    });
    model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 6) {
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                case 1:
                    return Integer.class;
                case 2:
                    return Double.class;
                case 3:
                    return Double.class;
            }
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            if (col == 3 & row == 5) {
                double sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    sum += ((Double) getValueAt(i, 3)).doubleValue();
                }
                return sum;
            }
            if (col == 3 & row != 5) {
                Integer i = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 1);
                Double d = (Double) getValueAt(row, 2);
                if (i != null && d != null) {
                    return i * d;
                } else {
                    return 0d;
                }
            }
            return super.getValueAt(row, col);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
            super.setValueAt(aValue, row, col);
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return col != 3;
        }
    };
    table = new JTable(model);
    TableColumn nameColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    nameColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(credit));
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.add(dateLabel);
    frame.add(dateField);
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    frame.add(saveButton);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Table1();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Whenever you get an exception and you post a question here regarding the exception, post the stack trace and also mention the line it's pointing to.

Comment: What is `where Date = i5Date1` supposed to achieve?

Comment: You need to change the driver.

Comment: @peeskillet - java.lang.NumberFormatException : For input string : ""

Comment: an empty string can't be parsed to a valid number - to have to guard your code against it

Comment: @kleopatra - you mean the empty cells in the JTable right? What can i do about it?

Comment: @AaronDigulla - i5Date1 is the string which is inputted from the textfield, and Date is the column in the database, it should achieve some thing like the "Total_Credit" value should be stored on the same line as of the date.

Comment: @Toms: Writing `"where Date = i5Date1"` will not magically make the value of the Java variable `i5Date1` visible to the database. Java makes no attempt to understand what's inside a SQL query inside of a String. You need to use `ps.setString()` instead.